# Error using Byte Buddy on Android

Tags: java, android, byte-buddy

I'm trying to use [Byte Buddy](http://bytebuddy.net/#/) library in Android but I get an error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: This JVM's version string does not
>   seem to be valid: 0

I have coded nothing yet, just:

```
ByteBuddy test = new ByteBuddy();
```

in my App.java

I have imported:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
    <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.7</version>
</dependency>
```

but it didn't work, to I tried with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
    <artifactId>byte-buddy-android</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.7</version>
</dependency>
```

but I still get same error.

**EDIT**

I have put this line before initialize ByteBuddy:

```
  System.setProperty("java.version", "1.7.0_51");
```

But now I get this another error:

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: can't load this
>   type of class file.

for this code:

```
Class<?> dynamicType = new ByteBuddy(ClassFileVersion.JAVA_V6)
            .subclass(Object.class)
            .method(ElementMatchers.named("toString"))
            .intercept(FixedValue.value("Hello World!"))
            .make()
            .load(getClass().getClassLoader(), AndroidClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
            .getLoaded();
```

Comment: On Android, try adding the class file version explicitly: new ByteBuddy(ClassFileVersion.JAVA_6), the Android dependency contains an Android specific ClassLoadingStrategy.

Comment: I have changed the class loading strategy to the Android one and specified the ClassFileVersion but I still get the same error.

Comment: You are not using the Android class loading strategy. The Default strategies do not work there. Instantiate one using "new".

Comment: `AndroidClassLoadingStrategy` constructor need a "privateDirectory" `File`. What should I pass?

Comment: It works!! In AndroidClassLoadingStrategy I have passed `context.getDir("dexgen", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`. Thanks!!

Comment: It depends on the API version used but what you do is correct. Alternatively, use the code cache directory. See the javadoc for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because **java.version** returns **0** in **Android** (See section System Properties [here - Comparison of Java and Android API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_Android_API))

Also, if you observe [ByteBuddy ClassFileVersion](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/blob/master/byte-buddy-dep/src/main/java/net/bytebuddy/ClassFileVersion.java)

**forCurrentJavaVersion()** : This method checks for ***versionString*** which should return any valid Java/JDK version else it

```
throws IllegalStateException("This JVM's version string does not seem to be valid: " + versionString);
```

& since **java.version** is returning **0**, it's throwing **IllegalStateException**.

Try to log this value:

```
String versionString = System.getProperty(JAVA_VERSION_PROPERTY);
Log.d(TAG, versionString);//retruns 0 here
```

hence workaround for this issue is to add

```
 System.setProperty(JAVA_VERSION_PROPERTY, "1.7.0_79");//add your jdk version here
```

before calling

```
ByteBuddy test = new ByteBuddy();
```

where **JAVA_VERSION_PROPERTY** is declared as:

```
 private static final String JAVA_VERSION_PROPERTY = "java.version";
```

Also **dependency** to use is:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
<artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
<version>0.7.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Else if you are using studio, you can add

```
compile 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:0.7.7'
```

to your app **build.gradle**.

Hope this will help solve your issue.